# Call a POST method (REST) from a webservice

Tags: web-services, rest, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use WWW and WWWForm to call my POST method of a webservice to save scores.

My service is working, I tested it using the Advanced REST Client of Chrome:

[image]

The problem is in the client side... I have the following function to call my service:

```
public IEnumerable saveScore(String name, float score)
{
        Debug.Log("POSTING");
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("dummy", "something");

        Dictionary<String, String> headers = form.headers;
        byte[] rawData = form.data;
        headers["arqamUserName"] = name;
        headers["arqamUserScore"] = score.ToString();

        // Post a request to an URL with our custom headers
        Debug.Log("CREATING WWW");
        WWW www = new WWW(url, rawData, headers);
        yield return www;
        Debug.Log("HAVE RESULTS");
        //.. process results from WWW request here...
        if (www.error!= null)
        {
             Debug.Log("Erro: " + www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("All OK");
            Debug.Log("Text: " + www.text);
        }
}
```

And then, I just call the above function:

```
private bool test = false;

void Update()
{
    if (!test)
    {
        Debug.Log("Starting POST");
        Scores.getInstance().saveScore("POST", 50);
        Debug.Log("Finished POST");
        test = true;
    }
}
```

I have done other c# clients using restsharp... But I am having problems when doing it in Unity.

When I run my game and the function saveScore() is called, I get this Output:

```
Starting POST
Finished POST
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method should not return IEnumerable but most likely IEnumerator since you are using coroutine.

And since it is a coroutine, you need to use the following to trigger it:

```
 StartCoroutine(Scores.getInstance().saveScore("POST", 50));
```

Comment: Thank you, just changed those 2 things and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If POSTING doesn't show up your function is not called.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I actually call the method... I edited my question, with the method that calls it and the full output I have.